# Anaconda Navigator - Incorrect App Update Notifications

Tags: powershell, version-control, anaconda, conda, spyder

I'm confused by Anaconda Navigator's (v2.4.1) app update notifications. For example, with Spyder (which is installed in my case), there is a notification to update to version 5.4.3. However, when I (a) open the app and check its version, and (b) go to the Powershell prompt and run the "conda list" command, both indicate 5.4.3 is already installed. This is all within "base (root)".

[Spyder app inside Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oDmd.png)

If I click the Refresh button in Anaconda Navigator, there's no change at all. Navigator still shows the notification to update the app. Shutting down Navigator and re-launching it makes no difference either.

Why is this happening? A bug in Anaconda Navigator?

In case it's relevant, I am using the Windows version on Win 11 64-bit.